# Can i call one application from another application?

Tags: android

i want to call Home-Screen launcher [Home-Screen](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html) app from my application's activity. can i call it??

please suggest me how to integrate it?

Comment: u want to call launcher from your app.?

Comment: @capdroid yes....how to do please tell me?

Comment: @capDroid where it is???i didnt found your ans!!

Comment: @capddeoid yup gt it....thank  alot.....but it will call our home screen or it will call new home screen?

Comment: our home or new home means..?

Comment: @CapDroid our home means default home screen and our means our own Home-screen.

Comment: i didn't test so i cant say.. in your side which home screen called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this..

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send an intent with category `CATEGORY_HOME`

Your code might look as follows:

> Intent i = new Intent();
>
> i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
>
> i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
>
> startActivity(i);

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

use intent and startActivity and pass the category name in intent

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.fuelgauge.PowerUsageSummary");

intent.setComponent(cn);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity( intent);
```

[See Here...](https://web.archive.org/web/20200710235813/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/launching-other-application-using-code.html)